# Object index reference

Tags: javascript

I've created a object

```
var slider = {
    this.config = {
        color : "white",
        width: 200,
        maxWidth : //here I want to insert value of "slider.config.width" * 1.5
        }
}
```

And I want to set a value of "maxWidth" to "width * 1.5".

How can I do it?

Comment: You can't refer to object during creation. You should store 200 in some variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had difficulties to make work your object on jsfiddle, but I made something similar :

http://jsfiddle.net/06c07qgj/19/

```
var slider = {

    color : "white",
    width: 200,
    maxWidth : function(e){ this.maxWidth = this.width*1.5;}
};

slider.maxWidth();

alert(slider.maxWidth);
```

Are you sure that your object doesnt look like something like this actually :

```
var slider = {
 config : {
    color : "white",
    width: 200,
    maxWidth :  //here I want to insert value of "slider.config.width" * 1.5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myWidth = 200;
var slider = {
    this.config = {
        color : "white",
        width: myWidth,
        maxWidth : function(){return this.width * 1.5;}
        }
}
console.log(maxWidth());
```

Assuming this is going to be created more than once.

And a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Modred/fs8pt64u/

Comment: Yeah, I know this way. I was curious if it's possible to refer to the argument inside the same object.

Comment: You could try an anonymous function, 
maxWidth : function(){return this.width * 1.5;}

Answer (score -1):

```
var slider = {
config : {
    color : "white",
    width: 200,
    }
}

var newObj = Object.create(slider.config);

newObj.maxWidth = newObj.width*1.5

alert(newObj.width);

alert(newObj.maxWidth );
```

Comment: Have you even tested?